# Only select records that do not start within the time frame of another record

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to achieve the following goal using MS SQL Server 2005 but do not know how to do it.

The goal is to select only records that do not start within the same time period as an anchor record.

Rows that have same ID are a group and evaluated as part of that group.

Start with the earliest date (A) based on StartDate, compare to the next row (B) that has the same ID.

If B starts within A, mark B as invalid. Continue to compare A against all remaining records that have the same ID.  Mark any starting within A as invalid.

Flag the next record that does not overlap with A as Valid.  Now repeat the same process as above (i.e. check to see if any subsequent records start within the time frame of the new valid record).

Repeat this process until all records have been analyzed.

Example:  Create the following table.

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#Dates') is not null drop table #Dates

create table #Dates (ID int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)
Insert into #Dates
Select 1, '7/23/2003'   ,   '8/22/2003'  union all
select 1, '8/21/2003'   ,   '11/19/2003' union all
select 1, '11/18/2003'  ,   '12/18/2003' union all
select 1, '12/17/2003'  ,   '1/16/2004'  union all
select 1, '1/15/2004'   ,   '2/14/2004'  union all
select 1, '2/11/2004'   ,   '2/26/2004'  union all
select 1, '9/14/2004'   ,   '10/14/2004' union all
select 1, '10/5/2004'   ,   '10/20/2004' union all
select 1, '11/20/2004'  ,   '12/20/2004' union all
select 1, '12/19/2004'  ,   '1/18/2005'  union all
select 1, '1/12/2005'   ,   '1/27/2005'  union all
select 1, '2/27/2005'   ,   '3/11/2005'
```

Expected output after applying the overlap logic rules:

```
ID  StartDate   EndDate     Valid
--  ---------   ---------   -----
1   7/23/2003   8/22/2003   1
1   8/21/2003   11/19/2003  0
1   11/18/2003  12/18/2003  1
1   12/17/2003  1/16/2004   0
1   1/15/2004   2/14/2004   1
1   2/11/2004   2/26/2004   0
1   9/14/2004   10/14/2004  1
1   10/5/2004   10/20/2004  0
1   11/20/2004  12/20/2004  1
1   12/19/2004  1/18/2005   0
1   1/12/2005   1/27/2005   1
1   2/27/2005   3/11/2005   1
```

Comment: *Note, this website is where you can ask questions regarding specific programming problems. This is just an assignment requirement with no discernable question. Post any code you have written so far to achieve this.

Comment: Which flavour of SQL?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the goal stated but do not know how to do it.  I'm using MS SQL Server 2005.  I have tried using some recursion but unfortunately it's nothing close to what I trying to achieve.  I really don't have any "useful code" to post because I do not know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Your sample results don't fit the description.  The second row, for instance, has no end dates prior to it, so it should be in the output.

Comment: Yes, Gordon, you're correct, I had a heck of a time trying to get the expected results to paste in correctly.  I think I have it correct now.  While editing the HTML I must've deleted a bunch of the expected outputs.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to answer my own question.  Used recursive SQL after ordering the records using row_number.

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#Dates') is not null drop table #Dates

create table #Dates (ID int, StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime)
Insert into #Dates
Select 1, '7/23/2003'   ,   '8/22/2003'  union all
select 1, '8/21/2003'   ,   '11/19/2003' union all
select 1, '11/18/2003'  ,   '12/18/2003' union all
select 1, '12/19/2004'  ,   '1/18/2005'  union all
select 1, '1/12/2005'   ,   '1/27/2005'  union all
select 1, '2/27/2005'   ,   '3/11/2005'  union all
select 1, '12/17/2003'  ,   '1/16/2004'  union all
select 1, '1/15/2004'   ,   '2/14/2004'  union all
select 1, '2/11/2004'   ,   '2/26/2004'  union all
select 1, '9/14/2004'   ,   '10/14/2004' union all
select 1, '10/5/2004'   ,   '10/20/2004' union all
select 1, '11/20/2004'  ,   '12/20/2004'


--Phase 1:  Apply ordering to dates
if object_id ('tempdb..#OrderedRecords') is not null drop table #OrderedRecords 

select *, N = row_number () over (partition by ID order by StartDate asc, EndDate desc)
into #OrderedRecords
from #Dates


--Phase 2:  Apply Overlap Rules (Subsume records that overlap)    
;with Subsume (ID, N, StartDate, EndDate, IntermediateStartDate, IntermediateEndDate, Valid) as
(
    select  ID, N, StartDate, EndDate, IntermediateStartDate = StartDate, IntermediateEndDate = EndDate,         
            Valid = 1
    from    #OrderedRecords 
    where   N = 1
    UNION ALL   
    select  c.ID, c.N, y.StartDate, y.EndDate,
            IntermediateStartDate = case when c.StartDate between y.IntermediateStartDate and y.IntermediateEndDate then y.IntermediateStartDate else c.StartDate end, 
            IntermediateEndDate  = case when c.StartDate between y.IntermediateStartDate and y.IntermediateEndDate then y.IntermediateEndDate else c.EndDate end,               
            Valid = case when (c.StartDate between y.IntermediateStartDate and y.IntermediateEndDate) then 0 else 1 end
    from    #OrderedRecords c
    join    Subsume y
            on  y.ID = c.ID
            and y.N = c.n - 1
            and y.IntermediateStartDate >= c.EndDate
    UNION ALL   
    select  c.ID, c.N, c.StartDate, c.EndDate,
            IntermediateStartDate = case when c.StartDate between y.IntermediateStartDate and y.IntermediateEndDate then y.IntermediateStartDate else c.StartDate end, 
            IntermediateEndDate  = case when c.StartDate between y.IntermediateStartDate and y.IntermediateEndDate then y.IntermediateEndDate else c.EndDate end,
            Valid = case when (c.StartDate between y.IntermediateStartDate and y.IntermediateEndDate) then 0 else 1 end
    from    #OrderedRecords c
    join    Subsume y
            on  y.ID = c.ID
            and y.N = c.n - 1
            and y.IntermediateStartDate < c.EndDate
)

Select ID, StartDate, EndDate, Valid
from Subsume
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```